# Specifying different colour schemes for different orientations of Polarhistogram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rose-plot

### Question

When using `polarhistogram(theta)` to plot a dataset containing azimuths from 0-360 degrees. Is it possible to specify colours for given segments?

### Example

In the plot bellow for example would it be possible to specify that all bars between 0 and 90 degrees (and thus 180-270 degrees also) are red? whilst the rest remains blue?

[image]

### Reference material

I think if it exists it will be within here somewhere but I am unable to figure out which part exactly:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polaraxes-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use `rose`, you can extract the edges of the histogram and plot each bar one by one. It's a bit of a hack but it works, looks pretty and does not require Matlab 2016b.

```
theta = atan2(rand(1e3,1)-0.5,2*(rand(1e3,1)-0.5));
n = 25;
colours = hsv(n);

figure;
rose(theta,n); cla; % Use this to initialise polar axes
[theta,rho] = rose(theta,n); % Get the histogram edges
theta(end+1) = theta(1); % Wrap around for easy interation
rho(end+1) = rho(1); 
hold on;
for j = 1:floor(length(theta)/4)
    k = @(j) 4*(j-1)+1; % Change of iterator
    h = polar(theta(k(j):k(j)+3),rho(k(j):k(j)+3));
    set(h,'color',colours(j,:)); % Set the color
    [x,y] = pol2cart(theta(k(j):k(j)+3),rho(k(j):k(j)+3));
    h = patch(x,y,'');
    set(h,'FaceColor',colours(j,:),'FaceAlpha',0.2);
    uistack(h,'down');
end
grid on; axis equal;
title('Coloured polar histogram')
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Ok great thanks. This is a starting point but as MATLAB recommends not using Rose maybe this isn't the ideal solution? Is it also possible to 'hack' Polarhistogram? The main issue I seem to come across with 'rose' is that segments that contain the same  count of data end up different lengths.

Comment: @AlexanderPeace I'm sorry but I can't help you there. I have Matlab 2015b and so no access to `polarhistogram`. I do think something analogous to my `rose` solution could be done with `[N,edges] = histcounts` to get the histogram and `cart2pol` to plot it in polar coordinates. It's still a heavy workaround though.

Comment: As far as I looked at the documentation of `polarhistogram`, all the bars are plotted in one go and so you're going to have quite a difficult time getting only one of them to be different color. Almost certainly you'll need to plot a single bar of different color separately.